# How to make a message send on certain days and hours on discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

All my code hasn't worked yet and was wondering how I could do it

Comment: This is really too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. You should ask this question in a Discord development forum.

Answer (score 0):

The way you ask is too broad for Stack overflow, like what user [@kevintechie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84901/kevintechie)
said. Anyway, for sending a message at a specific time, I recommend using [Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

The possible varibles of Cron are:

Seconds: 0-59

Minutes: 0-59

Hours: 0-23

Day of Month: 1-31

Months: 0-11 (January - December)

Day of Week: 0-6 (Sunday - Saturday)

Lets say you want to send a message everyday at 6 AM, using your local time

```
var cron = require("cron");

client.on('message', ...); //you don't have to add anything to the message listener

let morning = new cron.CronJob('00 00 06 * * *', () => {
  // Everyday at 6 AM, it will do something you want to it to do
  let channel = yourGuild.channels.get('id');
  channel.send('Morning everyone');
});
// to start the reminder
morning.start()
// to stop the reminder
morning.stop()
```

Else if you want it to remind from Mon to Fri, then it would be `...new cron.CronJob('00 00 06 * * 1-5', ()=> {...`